# getImageData causes "Uncaught Error: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9"

Tags: javascript, html, getimagedata, domexception

I'm trying to get a feel for some image manipulation in HTML5. I am finding that when I try and use the getImageData method I get this JS exception thrown. I am using Chrome and running on localhost.

Thanks!

Comment: Might need a little more context. Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121142/javascript-getimagedata-for-canvas-html5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833883/weird-chrome-prototype-jquery-conflict

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay figured out what the problem was. All I have to say is "derp". I was using

```
getImageData(x, x)
```

but the way I was intending to use this requires 4 arguments

```
getImageData(x,x,x,x)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with editing files on your local system using Chrome.  You can close Chrome and reopen it using flags --allow-file-access-from-files to allow local file editing.

Came across [this post](http://halufa.blogspot.com/2011/03/securityerr-on-chrome-using.html) when I ran into a similar issue and it helped.