# Uncaught Error: NotSupportedError: DOM Exception 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, createjs

I am developing a game(using html5, createJS,Canvas)  which is loading successfully on wamp servr locally, but it generate error on web server as below.

```
Uncaught Error: NotSupportedError: DOM Exception 9 prototype.js:1263
document._getElementsByXPath prototype.js:1263
document.getElementsByClassName prototype.js:1272
a jquery-1.9.0.min.js:2
st.fn.extend.find jquery-1.9.0.min.js:2
st.fn.st.init jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
st jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
(anonymous function) index.php:95
f jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
p.fireWith jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
st.extend.ready jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
```

What may be the cause ?

Thank
Anil Kumar

Comment: Using prototype from google cdn or another external domain?

Comment: we are using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1
 http://jquery.com/

Comment: checkout this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302842/getimagedata-causes-uncaught-error-not-supported-err-dom-exception-9

Comment: Thanks a lot Konga Raju. I have followed your mentioned link and found satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was getting "NotSupportedError: DOM Exception 9" from cordova app on ios while the code worked fine in desktop Safari & Chrome.  I was accessing an SVG element, with `element.children[0].children[0]` & `element.children[0].children[1]`. Element was a containing `div`; `children[0]` was `svg`; and `children[0]` & `children[1]`, `rect` and `text`, respectively.

The DOM appeared to be correctly constructed.

Turns out that in some environments, in my case mobile Safari, SVG is treated ONLY as XML, therefore you need to access with...

```
element.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0];
element.getElementsByTagName('text')[0];
```

All was fine thereafter.