# Call multiple functions onSubmit without page refreshing

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

My function fires onSubmit of a form and calls two other functions but I don't want the page to refresh.

```
$('form').submit(function(){

        functionA()
        functionB();
        return false;
});

function functionB(){

    var image = new Image();
        var canvas = document.getElementById("flag");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    image = context.getImageData(); 

    alert('remove');
}
```

This works fine when I only call functionA and when functionB is empty so I assume the problem must be in functionB?

EDIT.

My canvas is defined in a separate HTML file like so:

```
    <canvas id="flag"></canvas>
```

The console says Uncaught Error: NotSupportedError: DOM Exception 9

Comment: Where's `canvas` defined? What does your console (F12) say?

Comment: `;` is missing after `functionA()` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getImageData` is a method on the `context` object you retrieve using `getContext()`. The canvas element has no such method directly.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('flag');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

image = context.getImageData();
```

I've also not seen `getImageData` being used without any parameters, and can't find it documentated that this is supported. Normally, you pass 4 parameters specifiying `x, y, width, height`; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Comment: @db579: This seems to be caused by you not providing the required parameters to `getImageData()`; see [getImageData causes "Uncaught Error: NOT\_SUPPORTED\_ERR: DOM Exception 9"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10342969)